# Transaction log is full

Tags: sql-server

Can somebody please, let me know that how can we find out that the transaction log is full OR How can we figure out that what is causing the transaction log to grow.. Please, help.

Thanks,

Comment: you have asked 18 questions and accepted none of them.

Answer (score 6):

The transaction log in a user database will grow because the database is set to full recovery, and the transaction log is not being backed up.  If you don't need the ability to do point in time restores then you should change the database recovery from full to simple.

If you do need point in time restores then you need to start backing up the transaction log.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read through this, see if it helps - [Managing Transaction logs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/64582/)

If the log is filling up, generally either the max size is too small or you're running in full/bulk-logged recovery model and you're not backing the log up.

Answer (score 0):

This probably belongs on ServerFault.com

Short answer is, however, lots of reads/writes is causing this.  Increase the size of the log or run DB maintenance and backups more frequently.

Comment: Specifically log backups